# Kernel panic after update/upgrade on VirtualBox (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: kernel, updates

I have tried to update and upgrade my Ubuntu version and after updating, my boot screen is displaying a kernel panic message and I'm unable to access my login screen. I believe that part of the update was the kernel.

[image: screenshot]

There is a similar question posted on StackExchange for Ubuntu 16.04, which says to replace the kernel, but I am unsure if this applies to my problem. I don't understand what the output is telling me.

I am using VirtualBox Version 6.1.12 r139181 (Qt5.6.2) for this installation.

Comment: Can you boot into another kernel?

Comment: No, I've tried others, but they all go into a kernel panic.

Comment: What did you last do  ,  it look like you failed a kernel recompilation and rebooted

Comment: I performed an apt get-update and then and apt-get upgrade. During the upgrade there was a Windows blue screen and now this is what happens when I start Ubuntu within the VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot your VM, then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> button to get into **grub**, select another kernel.

If not try selecting recovery option in kernel.

Edit , if you cannot boot then you need to use a  live linux boot , then chroot into the hosed system a

Comment: I used "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" to try out different options under Grub, but all have the kernel problem. That includes trying all in recovery mode. So I load a Linux from install disk, and correct from in there? I need to chroot and then... install a new kernel? I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager in Windows. So I start the live Ubuntu within the VirtualBox, and I can access it like that?

Comment: That is correct , you can select the ubuntu.iso from the options menu in virtual box , under cd/dvd and set boot order for the cd/dvd to  be higher there too

Comment: Thanks. I have done that, I loaded from a live CD, used chroot to try to do a new update/upgrade - I used the instructions for "update failure" in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery However, I now get the error "apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: invalid ELF header"

Comment: Glad you could fix it  , good on ya :)

Comment: Not quite fixed - but making progress - do you have any advice to fix this error that I have now, please? I have recovered my files though, which is great, but would be nice to get the original setup working again.

Comment: Let me check , give  me a sec

Comment: If you are experiencing an invalid ELF header error, it is because the binaries included in your deployment package were built for a platform other than Linux. > What are you building/doing before the crash

Comment: How would I fix this? I was doing an apt-get update/upgrade when the crash happened. I think the crash was independent of the update/upgrade due to unstable Windows that the Virtualbox is running under (I need to fix that independently).

Comment: What happens now , when you start vm? , Also what cpu are you running?

Comment: Update: I copied the problematic file from the live CD and that has helped. Have more errors to look at now, but thanks.

Comment: CPU is an i5-8400. I will try to fix the errors before I restart the VM.

Comment: When I restart, I no longer get the kernel panic message, but it doesn't complete loading. When I was trying to complete the new update and upgrade with chroot, I saw problems with dpkg. I think it looks like my installation looks like there are multiple problems, which are not easy to fix, and I already fixed a few things. I think my installation got corrupted during the crash. I will probably do a clean install now that I have recovered my files. That will probably be quicker, and cleaner.

Comment: Fair enough , might want to  fix your rebooting pc first though

Comment: On 20.04 and just updated/upgraded and on reboot it panics before grub.