# kernel panic in virtual box 6.1.32

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm having a kernel panic in vbox 6.1.32, with ubuntu 18.04. W11 21H2 build 20000.675

I tried the "Try ubuntu only without installation" option but it doesn't reach any prompt (#). I reset the BIOS factory defaults.I disabled Hyper-V. I tried the recovery options but it also panics. I cannot even do a fresh install.

I followed this steps:
[Kernel panic after update/upgrade on VirtualBox (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307530/kernel-panic-after-update-upgrade-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-18-04) and tried a fresh install like here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=95425

The last time I was playing around with it was BIOS features to install ubuntu native on W11 under a SSD with secure boot enabled, and bitlocker. I remember I moved secure boot options but nothing for bitlocker.

Has anyone any idea why this could be happening?.

Thanks in advance.

[kernel panic on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P45MU.png)

Comment: `with ubuntu 18.04. W11 21H2 build 20000.675` -- Are you running virtualbox within WSL2?

Comment: If you are running VirtualBox within WSL, I suggest you run it outside WSL. Instead, run it in native Windows environment. VirtualBox has a Windows version.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I have a Virtual box running natively in windows not within WSL. thanks.

Comment: Hello all following this instructions fixed it: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390

Comment: usva.techdev thanks a bunch, the forums topic you recommended totally fixed it for me. Maybe add your solution to your question or answer your own question or something?  I don't want to steal your thunder!  I am using Ubuntu 20 and Virtualbox 6.1.34.

Comment: @usva.techdev yes, this should be posted as a solution to the question

Comment: Even with 4 CPUs it didn't work for me. "end kernel panic - not syncing: no working init found. try passing init= option to kernel."

Answer (score 27):

With me, a simpler setting solved the *Kernel Panic* problem.

Put **2 Processors** in the Virtual Machine settings

[image]

Comment: This is weird. With 1 or 4 processors not worked for me, but with 2 it has worked.

Comment: For me, it works with anything more than 1 processor.

Comment: Worked on Virtual BOX 6, running Ubuntu 22 on Windows 11!

Comment: 2 cpu works for me on virtualbox 6.

Comment: 2 CPU worked. ubuntu 22.04, Virtual Box 6, Windows 11

Comment: Even with 4 CPUs it didn't work for me.

Comment: 2 CPU worked with Windows 11 VirtualBox 6.1.44. Hyper-V also disabled.

Comment: On VBox 7.0 with CentOS it solved the problem when two plus processors configured.

Answer (score 7):

Increasing the no of processors will solve the problem. The kernel is set to use a single processor where the actual code is for at least two procrssors

Comment: This is a dupe of an existing answer.

Comment: This answer offers additional information to the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hello all following this instructions fixed it: [vbox forum answer](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390)

Here is a summary of what I did from the vbox forum quoting the forum content:

*"To turn Hyper-V off completely, do this:

1. Shut down all programs. You will have to shut down, unplug, and restart your host.
2. Look into I have a 64bit host, but can't install 64bit guests, 2nd post, points 2 & 3 and ensure that none of these things are running:
   DeviceGuard
   CredentialGuard
   Windows Defender's Core Isolation
3. Find the Command Prompt icon, right click it and choose Run As Administrator.
4. Enter this command:
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   Some report this command was needed also:
   DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
5. Enter this command:
   shutdown -s -t 2
6. When the computer turns off, unplug it for 20 seconds. Then plug it in again and boot up Windows 10."*

Comment: link-only answers are not usually appreciated here. Any number of things can happen to the contents of that web page. You can add a summary of the steps you took, taken from that link, in addition to the link, and that would be a much better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It is true that Virtualbox will work better and be faster with the method described here, but it may be wise to point out that this will break a lot of important Windows features. In particular, some security features are based on virtualization, as well as WSL 2 (WSL 1 will continue working on Windows 10. Windows 11 of course does not have WSL 1).

Answer (score 1):

In my recent experience with WIN 11 with VBox  6.1.34 clashes with WIN 11 Hyper-V & Virtual Platform service. In order to resolve it is required to uninstall those services.

1. On the search Type Windows Features On or Off
2. [Windows Feature Turn on or Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60qRv.png)
3. Then try to install Ubuntu on VBox
   This will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same problem is solved by adding the CPU from 1 to 4. The step is Setting->System->Processor.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to install ubuntu workstation on Virtual box and instead installed Ubuntu Server first and then ran:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

reboot and you're good to go. You can also choose other desktops besides gnome.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on initial startup with:

- Lubuntu 22.04
- VirtualBox 6.1.48
- Windows 10 with Hyper-V enabled
  which means I couldn't even boot the ISO to attempt installation in VirtualBox.

I tried various amendments, including amending the Acceleration, Graphics Controller and increasing to 2 processors, but none of these made any difference.

When I increased the memory from 1024 MB to 2048 MB the problem went away.