# Does anyone know why Ubuntu won't install on Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install ubtuntu-20.04.1 on virtualbox 6.1.40. I am following this guide - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview
When I press start, instead of loading the installer for ubuntu image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrvyG.png) pops up.

I have followed something to turn of HyperV but that hasn't changed anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also I am on a windows 11 laptop with an i7-11390H, with 8gb ram and a 500gb SSD.

#### What happens when I try to load my Virtual Box

[image: What happens when I try to load my Virtual Box]

#### After selecting the first option

[image: After selecting the first option]

---

Thanks for the help, but the suggestion that helped was from @ARG, I increased the processor and ram allowance and eventually it loaded to allow installation

Comment: You no longer can run the installer directly from the boot menu. instead you should choose the first item from the boot menu which is "Try or Install Ubuntu". after the ubuntu is fully loaded you can run the installer from the desktop.

Comment: @jedd-rixon-gibb how many processors have you assigned to the virtual machine?

Comment: @ali129 I have attached a photo of what happens when I try to select "Try or Install Ubuntu" and it just crashes the boot menu

Comment: @ARG I have now changed it from 1 to 4 and I have doubled the available RAM to it. It will load a Ubuntu graphic but it is now just a black screen, EDIT - eventually it has loaded to the main installation screen. THANKS!

Comment: Changing the number of processors suggests a duplicate of [kernel panic in virtual box 6.1.32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408595/kernel-panic-in-virtual-box-6-1-32)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was the same issue as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408595/kernel-panic-in-virtual-box-6-1-32).

Increasing the number of processors to greater than 1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on follow way:

- Create new machine by your VirtualBox.
- On this machine create by Virtual Box a empty virtual disk, pe. a .vmdk.
- Add your downloaded bootable Ubuntu ISO to your created VM.
- Set Configure the ISO as boot medium and not the .vmdk file
- Boot your VM from Ubuntu ISO
- Install the Ubuntu on your .vmdk
- Shut down your VM
- Remouve the Ubuntu ISO from your VM
- Set the .vmdk as boot medium
- Boot your VM with your installed Ubuntu.